# How can I use Math::Business::EMA with DBI to calculate exponential moving averages in Perl?

Tags: perl, finance, stocks

Script pulls data from mysql:

```
$DBI::result = $db->prepare(qq{
    SELECT close 
    FROM $table 
    WHERE day <= '$DATE' 
    ORDER BY day DESC 
    LIMIT $EMA
 });
$DBI::result->execute();

while($row = $DBI::result->fetchrow) {
    print "$row\n";
};
```

with the following example results:

```
1.560
1.560
1.550...
```

But I need to work out the EMA using [Math::Business::EMA](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math::Business::EMA); and I'm not sure how to calculate this while maintaining the accuracy. EMA is weighted and My lack of Perl knowledge is not helping.

Answer (score 2):

First, some comments on the code:

1. You do not seem to be using [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html). You should.
2. You seem to think it is OK to trample all over the `DBI` namespace. It is not.
3. You should use [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) instead of interpolating into the SQL string.

Now, for the actual task (untested code):

```
my $averager = Math::Business::EMA->new;
$averager->set_days(3);

my $sth = $db->prepare(sprintf q{
    SELECT close 
    FROM  %s
    WHERE day <= ? 
    ORDER BY day DESC 
    LIMIT ?
}, $table);

$sth->execute($DATE, $EMA); # what is $EMA?
while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref ) {
    $averager->insert( $row->[0] );
    my $avg = $averager->query;
    $avg = 'n/a' unless defined $avg;
    print "$avg\n";
}
```